# Rails version migration issue (Rails 4.2 to 5.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

When migrating from rails `4.2.6` to `5.0.1`, I am getting some errors:

```
undefined method `push' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:
```

while doing:

```
@users = User.includes(:account).order(:last_name)
@users.push(new_user)
```

Comment: Is this `undefined method push' for #` the complete error ? There must be a class name after **#** I believe.

Comment: This is the complete line :    undefined method `push' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000000aba23b8>

Comment: Did you try Deepak's answer ? That should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

One point to note here is `@users` is `ActiveRecord` relation. There is no such method `push` for `ActiveRecord` relation.

`push` method is supported by `Array`, So you can convert the result into an array and then push the `new_user` in the resulting `Arraya

```
@users = User.includes(:account).order(:last_name)
@users.to_a.push(new_user)
```

Comment: Also it is mentioned that concat and push works identically.But concat not working .Getting the same error.

Comment: @Deepak Mahakale  - Thank you for your answer to this.  `@users.to_a.push...` helped me.  I had this same issue and was trying to add the `to_a` to my new_record.

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveRecord::Associations::AssociationCollection#push` has been [deprecated and removed](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/AssociationCollection/push) from `ActiveRecord 5`. You may try to convert relation to array before pushing:

```
@users = User.includes(:account).order(:last_name).to_a
@users.push(new_user)
```

or find similar method available in ActiveRecord 5. For example [there is concat method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L113):

```
@users = User.includes(:account).order(:last_name)
@users.concat([new_user])
```

Comment: Yes ,the push method has been deprecated,but it would be good if you could tell any other method in place of it